# Can anyone help identify this spigot?

Tags: spigot

[image]

The valve stem is broken off. I would like to find a replacement valve stem because removing the entire faucet is impossible without replumbing.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any way to identify this exact valve but they are pretty much available in home stores. Turn off the water to that spigot and remove the top nut and take out the valve stem. Bring it to your home store or to a plumbing supply store and look for a replacement. This doesn't appear to be a regular gate valve so you have that going for you. It looks like you'd be able to remove that spigot and just replace it. You'd probably have to secure the pipe on the other side of the wall while removing the spigot.

Answer (score 1):

There are signs that this is threaded onto a pipe nipple sticking out of the wall. It’s designed to take a wrench here. Now that being said, it looks like it’s been on there for decades. I would try it gently and hope for luck. Is there any way to get at the back side and steady that while you try to turn this off?

[image]